# Resource file translator

Tags: .net, resources, google-translate

I'm thinking of writing a app to read .net resouce files, loop through the text entries sending them to google translate, and creating a new resouce file for the various languages. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a similar application using the Bing translator - check out my example of how to use it here:

http://www.jimmycollins.org/blog/?p=241

The one thing to watch out for is if Google has any limits on how many requests you can send it (e.g. in a minute). I had to put in some logic to get around this exact problem when using Bing.

Comment: I might just add Bing as an option to do the translations ;)

Answer (score 1):

The result will be plain awful and in many cases complete nonsense.

Many strings in an application is just one word without context and that can translate into many different words in other languages depending on the context, but to Google translate the context would be unknown and Google translate would have no idea how to best translate the word.

Comment: That's true, but my intent is to create a starting point for local resources to edit the resouce. Basicaly I dont want to have to do the changes and/or create a new resouce every time someone requests it.

Comment: This is true of any free MT solution. But it can still be useful for internationalization testing. Machine translated strings will resemble content better that pseudo translation for example.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just copy the resource and insert `TODO:` in front of the English text, like `TODO:&Menu`?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Translate API has been [deprecated](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html) so you would want to look at a different provider.  Still, online translators will typically give poor results, especially when translating software and UI elements.